# how to use bottom space of mobile in video player?

Tags: android, react-native

I'm using react native video player when set it in fullscreen its set on fullscreen but bottom menu showing black space that space is not use for video player, how to use that space in video player?[image: here you can see mark area is not use for player]

video-player view Design

```
<View style={customStyles.videoWrapper}>
        {
            video.uri !== '' ?
                <Video
                    {...props}
                    style={[
                        styles.video,
                        this.getSizeStyles(),
                        style,
                        customStyles.video,
                    ]}
                    ref={p => {
                        this.player = p;
                    }}
                    muted={this.props.muted || this.state.isMuted}
                    paused={this.props.paused
                        ? this.props.paused || !this.state.isPlaying
                        : !this.state.isPlaying}
                    fullscreenOrientation={"all"}
                    onProgress={this.onProgress}
                    onEnd={this.onEnd}
                    onBuffer={this.onBuffer}
                    onLoad={this.onLoad}
                    source={video}
                    fullscreen={this.state.isFullscreen}
                    resizeMode={resizeMode}
                    rate={this.props.rate}
                /> :
                <View style={[this.getSizeStyles(), {backgroundColor: '#000'}]}/>
        }

        <View
            style={[
                this.getSizeStyles(),
                {marginTop: -this.getSizeStyles().height}
            ]}
        >
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.overlayButton}
                onPress={() => {
                    this.showControls();
                    if (pauseOnPress)
                        this.onPlayPress();
                }}
                onLongPress={() => {
                    if (fullScreenOnLongPress && Platform.OS !== 'android')
                        this.onToggleFullScreen();
                }}
            />
            {this.state.isBuffering ? this.renderBuffer() :
                (this.state.isControlsVisible)
                    ? this.renderControls() : null}
        </View>

    </View>
```

video style

```
 video: {
       backgroundColor: 'black',
 },
```

here getStyle function set it's height and width with ratio.

```
getSizeStyles() {
    const {videoWidth, videoHeight} = this.props;
    const {width} = this.state;
    const ratio = videoHeight / videoWidth;

    if (this.state.isFullscreen) {
        return {
            width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
            height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
        }
    }

    return {
        height: width * ratio,
        width,
    };
}
```

i have create fullScreen function with orientation it will when orientation change.

```
onToggleFullScreen() {
console.log("PixelRatio ",PixelRatio.startDetecting)
if (this.props.onFullscreen) {
    this.props.onFullscreen(!this.state.isFullscreen);
}

this.state.isFullscreen ? Orientation.lockToPortrait() : Orientation.lockToLandscapeLeft();

if (this.player !== null) {
    this.player.presentFullscreenPlayer();
}

if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
    this.onAndroidFullScreenToggle();
}
this.setState({
    isFullscreen: !this.state.isFullscreen
});
```

}

Comment: where is the code? where is the snippet?

Comment: @NishargShah please check now.

Comment: please create snippet/demo in codesandbox